# Creating simple search for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there any simple way to create search for Google App Engine for specific datastore table.
Just want to create basic text search for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google App Engine - Full Text Search](http://gae-text-search.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want full-text search over a `Text` field in a `Model`, try something like Bill Katz's [`SearchableModel`](http://www.billkatz.com/2009/6/Simple-Full-Text-Search-for-App-Engine).

Answer (score 2):

You can only do a full-text search not partials.

What you could do if you really need to do a simple search and depending on how many records you are going to have, is create a cron job that creates a blobstore with the table key and the field you want to search. Then just use the blobstore for your searches. Remove the lines that dont have the search field and display the field as the result , with the key as your link to the relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

Use Query Filter to search by specific column

See documentation [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html)